# Using a custom ordered list within a built-in ordered list

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I made an ordered list with `upper-alpha`, and then a custom list with a bracket after the number. Then I want to make a sublist using `list-style-type: lower-roman` but it doesn't work. Is there a way to stop the double listing? Creating my `lower-roman` custom list doesn't look good.

Problem seemed to occur only when I use a built-in list, and then a custom list, and then a built-in list again.

The CSS below doesn't work:

```
ol.listing {
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
ol.listing li ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol.listing li ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: counter(list)") "
}
ol.listing li ol li ol{
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

However, custom `lower-roman` seems to align roman to the left, instead of align right as in the `list-style-type:lower-roman`:

```
ol.listing {
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
ol.listing li ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol.listing li ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: counter(list)") "
}
ol.listing li ol li ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: roman;
}
ol.listing li ol li ol> li:before {
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, lower-roman)". "
}
```

Sample HTML code to test with:

```
<ol class="listing">
    <li>Beverage
        <ol>
            <li>Cold Beverage
                <ol>
                    <li>Apple Juice</li>
                    <li>Sky Juice</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Hot Beverage
                <ol>
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Food</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase a bit the specifity of your selector where counter is inserted

```
ol.listing> li >ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: counter(list)") "
}
```

```css
ol.listing {
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
ol.listing li ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol.listing> li >ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: counter(list)") "
}
ol.listing li ol li ol{
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol class="listing">
    <li>Beverage
        <ol>
            <li>Cold Beverage
                <ol>
                    <li>Apple Juice</li>
                    <li>Sky Juice</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Hot Beverage
                <ol>
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Food</li>
</ol>
```

or size your pseudo and reset text-align:

```
ol.listing li ol li ol> li:before {
  width: 1.5em;/* size*/
  text-align: right;/* reset */
  display: inline-block;/* make it a box sizeable */
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, lower-roman)". "
}
```

```css
ol.listing {
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
ol.listing li ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol.listing li ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: counter(list)") "
}
ol.listing li ol li ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: roman;
}
ol.listing li ol li ol> li:before {
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
    counter-increment: roman;
    content: counter(roman, lower-roman)". "
}
```

```html
<ol class="listing">
    <li>Beverage
        <ol>
            <li>Cold Beverage
                <ol>
                    <li>Apple Juice</li>
                    <li>Sky Juice</li>
                    <li>Milk</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Hot Beverage
                <ol>
                    <li>Coffee</li>
                    <li>Tea</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Food</li>
</ol>
```